# SoupStrainer does not increase speed at all

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using a SoupStrainer in order to get a speed increase.
Without it, it takes around 12 seconds.
And using the SoupStrainer also results in 12 seconds.

I'm really new to python and wonder if I did something wrong.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer
from contextlib import closing
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
import time

def simple_get(url):
    try:
        with closing(get(url, stream=True, headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"})) as resp:
            return resp.content
    except RequestException as e:
        return None



if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGRcJQ9tMbY"

    raw_html = simple_get(url)

    bs4_video_list_item_filter = SoupStrainer(class_="video-list-item")
    start = time.time()
    html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, "lxml", parse_only=bs4_video_list_item_filter) #, 'html.parser')
    print("BeautifulSoup ", time.time()-start)
```

I really hope someone can help with speeding it up cause I need to do like 20.000.

Comment: Are you sure that the class "video-list-item" exists? I searched for it in the page source and didn't find such thing.

Comment: @QusaiAlothman I have it when I get the page from within python. If I go to the page in my browser directly then it is not there.

Comment: any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#improving-performance):

> Parsing only part of a document won’t save you much time parsing the document, but it can save a lot of memory, and it’ll make *searching* the document much faster.

So you actually won't gain any speed while parsing the document using `SoupStrainer`.